# Web scraper not collecting URLs

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, url, beautifulsoup

I am scraping [this website](https://www.judiciary.uk/prevention-of-future-death-reports/) to create a database.
I [have python code that successfully did this](https://github.com/georgiarichards/georgiarichards.github.io/blob/master/data/Web_scraper_PFDs.ipynb), but the HTML structure has completely changed.
I am trying to update my code to update the database, but my code cannot locate the URLs.
This is my new code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tqdm import tqdm

base_url = 'https://www.judiciary.uk/prevention-of-future-death-reports/page/{}/'
page_count = 442

with requests.Session() as session:
    record_urls = [ ]
    for page in tqdm(range(1, page_count + 1)):
        url = base_url.format(page)
        try:
            response = session.get(url)
            response.raise_for_status()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
            record_urls += [h5.a['href'] for h5 in soup.find_all('h5', {'class': 'entry-title'})]
        except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ValueError, AttributeError) as e:
            print(f"Failed to process page {page}: {e}")
    print(f"Collected {len(record_urls)} URLs")
```

Could anyone advise what HTML element contains the URLs or how to find this so my code can collect the ~4420 URLs?
Thank you!

I used 'selector gadget' and 'inspect' to locate the new strucutre. I tried swapping 'entry-title' with 'card__link' and then 'li' but none helped identify where the URLs now sit.

Comment: that is the issue with web scraping.  when the structure changes, the DOM changes...  you can right click on the page and do `inspect element` and look for something common...

Comment: inspecting the tags, it seems like you might need to change the headers of what is being looked for.... change `h5` to `h3` tags.  `h3_tags = soup.find_all('h3')`.

Comment: `card__link` is the class of the `<a>` tag, so it would be `soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'card__link'})` - you could also match on just the class name e.g. `record_urls += [ a['href'] for a in soup.find_all(class_='card__link') ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Below in your code from

```
record_urls += [h5.a['href'] for h5 in soup.find_all('h5', {'class': 'entry-title'})]
```

To

```
record_urls += [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'card__link'})]
```

Should extract url on all pages

Full code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tqdm import tqdm

base_url = 'https://www.judiciary.uk/prevention-of-future-death-reports/page/{}/'
page_count = 442

with requests.Session() as session:
    record_urls = []
    for page in tqdm(range(1, page_count + 1)):
        url = base_url.format(page)
        try:
            response = session.get(url)
            response.raise_for_status()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
            record_urls += [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'card__link'})]

        except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ValueError, AttributeError) as e:
            print(f"Failed to process page {page}: {e}")
   
    print(f"Collected {len(record_urls)} URLs")
```

Comment: Thank you! This now runs perfectly! All 4415 urls now collected